# GREP InDesign: How can I replace a string with another string within one line?

Tags: grep

I want to copy the name string into the href value and add a plus (several times, obviously, line by line). This is the text (I am just using InDesign because of 'easy' GREP support in this case):

```
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s=alex+feuerstein”>Andreas Zedtwitz</a>
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s=alex+feuerstein”>Angelika Arendt</a>
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s=alex+feuerstein”>Anna-Lena Lotz</a>
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s=alex+feuerstein”>Benjamin Köder</a>
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s=alex+feuerstein”>Betty Rieckmann</a>
```

...

1. The href value is selected with `(?<==)(\w+\+\w+)`
2. The string is selected with `(?<=>)(\w+ \w+)`

How do I tell it to replace 2. with 1.?

Thanks!

PS: The letter case should as in 2. (UPdown UPdown)

Comment: unclear, post the final desired result

Comment: "grep" is only a search tool. If you want to "search for a regex in the line, then replace another part of the line with the text you matched", you'll need a programming language. What programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: I don't know, I just want to have this result (but for more text obviously):
-------------------------------------------------
`<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s= Andreas+Zedtwitz”>Andreas Zedtwitz</a>

<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s= Angelika+Arendt”>Angelika Arendt</a>

<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s= Anna+Lotz”>Anna-Lena Lotz</a>

<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s= Benjamin+Köder”>Benjamin Köder</a>
<a href=”http://luisleu.de/?s= Betty+Rieckmann”>Betty Rieckmann</a>`